# cannot update in panel when i choose a file path

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, java-io

once a user selects the button "CLICK HERE TO UPLOAD", the3 file path is stored into a file, and these paths are read into an arraylist, which is shown on the JPanel. the problem is that once a file is selected, it is never updated automatically on the JPanel, unless the application is re runed, before the up to date number of information is displayed. How can this problem be rectified, because i have no clue where i have gone wrong. By the way the arraylists gets updated on runtime but the JPanel never gets updated.

```
public class Media2 extends JPanel {

private JPanel video_pnl, control_pnl;
private JButton play_btn;
private JLabel loc_lbl;
private int increment;
ArrayList<String> file_location;
ArrayList<JButton> button_lists;
private FileWriter file_writer;
private BufferedWriter buffered_writer;
private JFileChooser filechooser;
private File file;
private JButton btn_upload;
private BufferedReader br;
private FileReader fr;

public Media2(ArrayList<String> file_location) throws IOException {

    btn_upload = new JButton("Click here to Upload Video");
    String file_path = "C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\VDMS\\src\\VideoInfos.txt";
    file = new File(file_path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
        file_writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        file_writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
    }
    add(btn_upload);

    Handlers handler = new Handlers();
    btn_upload.addActionListener(handler);

    this.file_location = file_location;
    readFile(file_location, file_path);
}

private void readFile(ArrayList<String> file_location, String file_path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    fr = new FileReader(file_path);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String text = "";
    String line2;
    line2 = br.readLine();
    while (line2 != null) {
        int i = 0;
        file_location.add(i, line2);
        line2 = br.readLine();
        i++;
    }
    configurePanel(file_location);
    //System.out.print(file_location.size() + "in the read file 1");
}

private void configurePanel(ArrayList<String> file_location) {
    increment = 0;
    while (increment < file_location.size()) {

        video_pnl = new JPanel();
        video_pnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(video_pnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        loc_lbl = new JLabel();
        loc_lbl.setText(file_location.get(increment));
        control_pnl = new JPanel();
        control_pnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        video_pnl.add(loc_lbl);
        control_pnl.add(createButton(increment));

        video_pnl.add(control_pnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        video_pnl.revalidate();
        add(video_pnl);
        increment++;
    }
}

private JButton createButton(final int i) {
    play_btn = new JButton("Play");
    play_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                System.out.println(file_location.get(i));
            play(i);
        }
    });
    return play_btn;
}

public void play(int i) {
    System.out.println(file_location.get(i));
}

private class Handlers implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btn_upload) {
            try {   //display the image in jlabel
                file = new File("C:\\Users\\goldAnthony\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\VDMS\\src\\VideoInfos.txt");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    file_writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    file_writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
                }
                buffered_writer = new BufferedWriter(file_writer);
                //creating a file chooser
                filechooser = new JFileChooser();
                filechooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Your Video");
//            //below codes for select  the file 
                int returnval = filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                    String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    buffered_writer.write(filename);
                    buffered_writer.newLine();
                    buffered_writer.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException | HeadlessException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Declare and initialize local variables
    ArrayList<String> file_location = new ArrayList<>();

    //creates instances of the VlcPlayer object, pass the mediaPath and invokes the method "run"
    Media2 mediaplayer = new Media2(file_location);
    JFrame ourframe = new JFrame();
    ourframe.setContentPane(mediaplayer);
    ourframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    ourframe.setSize(300, 560);
    ourframe.setVisible(true);
    ourframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Comment: I think it would help, if you added more context info instead of just posting the whole application code. Now everyone has to figure out the context of the problem!

Comment: Changes to the GUI are preferably done on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which I don't see where you update... your problem is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

When you add components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

You are revalidating the wrong panel:

```
video_pnl.revalidate(); // wrong panel
add(video_pnl);
```

You should be doing:

```
//video_pnl.revalidate();
add(video_pnl);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: @MastaOpec, Then I guess I don't understand your question. Post a [MCTRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: From the Handler class  which updates the source file, never does anything to actually update the UI. Take a look and see what I mean, when you update your answer let me know so I can up vote it

Answer (score -1):

Your code needs some changes, try:

```
private void configurePanel(ArrayList<String> file_location) {

    increment = 0;
    while (increment < file_location.size()) {
        addEntry(file_location.get(increment));//--------->New line
        increment++;
    }
}

private void addEntry(String location) {//--------->New constructor
    video_pnl = new JPanel();
    video_pnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(video_pnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    loc_lbl = new JLabel();
    loc_lbl.setText(location);
    control_pnl = new JPanel();
    control_pnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    video_pnl.add(loc_lbl);
    control_pnl.add(createButton(increment));

    video_pnl.add(control_pnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    video_pnl.revalidate();
    add(video_pnl);
}
```

and:

```
 private class Handlers implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == btn_upload) {
                try {   //display the image in jlabel
                    file = new File("C:\\VideoInfos.txt");
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        file_writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        file_writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
                    }
                    buffered_writer = new BufferedWriter(file_writer);
                    //creating a file chooser
                    filechooser = new JFileChooser();
                    filechooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Your Video");
//            //below codes for select  the file 
                    int returnval = filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                    if (returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                        String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();
                        buffered_writer.newLine();
                        buffered_writer.write(filename);
                        buffered_writer.newLine();
                        buffered_writer.close();
                        addEntry(filename);//---------------->New Line
                        validate();//------------>New Line
                    }

                } catch (IOException | HeadlessException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now it's working. You have to make further changes, of course :)

Comment: There is not need to invoke the update(Graphics) method directly. Swing will do this when a component needs to be repainted.

Comment: If you reuse the component - and if you want to change the graphics while component is invisible - `update(getGraphics())` is very useful (I mean before setting component to visible). `repaint()` only works while componet is visible..

Comment: @MastaOpec - your goal is to add all JPanels to some JPanel vertically? If so - try to revalidate parent JPanel. You can try `pack()` also.

Comment: You can use `BoxLayout` also in parent `JPanel`.

Comment: Please, never suggest using update or getGraphics, you don't control the paint process, this is the responsibility of the repaint manager

Comment: But how to repaint component if it's invisible? Let's say I have static `JWindow` as a dialog, and after making it invisible, I make some changes to it, and then I set it to visible. Without `update(getGraphics())` - component repaints AFTER I set it to visible - so for a few milliseconds an old content is visible..

Comment: -1 for the horrible update(getGraphics) ... please read the painting article referenced in the swing tag wiki

Comment: @kleopatra - then please tell me how to repaint component when it is not visible?

Comment: _repaint_ and _!visible_ is a contradiction in itself ... what do you **really** want?

Comment: Please read my comments more closely - if you reusing the same component - if you want to make changes when it is invisible - and later will become visible.